# How to run specific sudo commands from (non-root) another linux user

Tags: linux, sudo

I have user `memsql`, I want to run below sudo commands from `memsql` linux user.

Commands:

```
    - 'sudo mv /tmp/memsql.service /home/memsql/memsql/memsql.service'
    - 'sudo systemctl disable /home/memsql/memsql/memsql.service'
    - 'sudo systemctl enable /home/memsql/memsql/memsql.service'
```

pls let me know how to allow this commands to run as sudo for `memsql` user and not from `root` user.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u memsql mv /tmp/memsql.service /home/memsql/memsql/memsql.service
etc.
```

Note that your `memsql` user should have enough privileges to execute the commands you have mentioned.